# Excel: Open in the first empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to let Excel automatically select the first empty cell in column A, whenever I open the document?

I have got the following to find the the first empty line:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Value + 1.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Value + 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "start an excel document..."? Do you want to output a value to the frist empty cell in column A or what is your goal?

Comment: Sorry. I meant open the file. I want to start writing in the first free line without manually scrolling to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get Excel to select the first empty cell in column A when you open your workbook, you need to place the following code in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

This will select the first empty cell in the `ActiveSheet`. If you got multiple sheets in your workbook and you want to select the first empty row in a specific sheet, say `Sheet1`, you should change the second line of code to:

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that.
You need write VBA(macro) program to realize.

Code you need is as follow

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    ActiveWindow.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Select
End Sub
```

Meaning of code is:

"Private Sub Workbook_Open()" is predefined name subroutine which will be executed when the workbook be opened.

"ActiveWindow.Range("A65536").End(xlUp)" will find last cell with data in A column ("last cell")
"ActiveWindow.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)" will move to cell next to "last cell", that will be first blank cell.
ActiveWindow.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Select will select tha first blank cell.

I assumed that you use Excel 2003 or older, OR number of rows with data in your worksheet is less than 65536. 
If you use Excel 2007 or newer and you have rows with data in your worksheet more than 65536, please modify 65536 to the value large enough to cover rows in your worksheet.

Comment: You cannot use the `Range` object within the `ActiveWindow` property. Your code will return an error.

Comment: Use ActiveSheet instead of ActiveWindow.